# Can I pass NSManagedObject into performBackgroundTask safely?

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-data, io

Question as in the subject. I have an array of subclasses of `NSManagedObject`s named `report`s. Now I want to make a lot of calculation on this data. It could take some time so I don't want block main thread.

```
let persistentContainer = DatabaseStack.shared.persistentContainer
persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (context) in
    //HERE: calculation on reports array
}
```

Should I refetch `reports` array inside `performBackgroundTask` using given background `context`. Which refetch method will be the best? Could you show me an example?

#### EDIT

I know that `NSManagedObject`s are not thread safe but I develop under iOS10 and I use `performBackgroundTask` method. I wonder if the method there does not deal with it

#### EDIT2

I add that for now everything works fine (I do not refetch objects) but I want to know for sure that this will be works always without random crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still not safe. The documentation explicitly stating this in the latest article, describing concurrency and queues:

> NSManagedObject instances are not intended to be passed between
>   queues. Doing so can result in corruption of the data and termination
>   of the application. When it is necessary to hand off a managed object
>   reference from one queue to another, it must be done through
>   NSManagedObjectID instances.
>
> You retrieve the managed object ID of a managed object by calling the
>   objectID method on the NSManagedObject instance.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html (at the bottom)

Using methods like perform assumes that you do implement atomic actions with the context (e.g create MOs and save them OR fetch MO and extract data for requesting logic etc.)

Comment: OK, so what should I do when objects have been fetched and I want to make some calculation on it without blocking main thread?

Comment: @KamilHarasimowicz, well it depends on either you want to save changes on calculations or not. If changes should be saved after calculations, you just do the whole thing inside your pefromBackgroundTask block. This method guarantees that that a private queue context will be created for this task and you will not block main queue. So, just fetch, calculate, modify MO, save context. If you need to do the calculation in another queue, just extract data you need and forward it. It is not safe to pass MO instances between different contexts, but it is save to use it with the same context.